# DOS choice batch command on Windows 2000 and higher (with default and timeout)

Tags: windows, batch-file

Pretty much explained in the topic - need a replacement for choice which can accept a default value and a timeout. SET /P doesn't cut it, unfortunately. Scripts are to be run in WinPE, so vbscript with IE is also out of question.

Comment: Do you can install an external file? Thats the easiest solution. A pure batch solution can be done, but it's really complex

Comment: I probably could write my own in C or something; maybe even reorganize some stuff so that it isn't needed anymore. I was mostly curious if such a thing exists. Kind of strange to take away this possibility from users.

Comment: It may be possible to get a copy of CHOICE.EXE off an old system, add it to your system, then do things the old way. As it's a separate executable, it doesn't really have any interactions with things like CMD.EXE. Once upon a time CHOICE.EXE was included in the NT Resource Kit.

Comment: Does 'SET /P' not work because it pauses to accept input? If so, then you can do 'ECHO VALUE |', replacing VALUE with whatever value, variable, etc. you want. It's also possible to redirect value from file as shown in http://ss64.com/nt/set.html at end of section 'Prompt for user input'.

Comment: @Baczek To avoid confusion - you're looking for is a command to be used in CMD.exe that allows you to choose an answer, but also has a default answer and timer that would choose the default if a choice is not made. Is this correct?

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific than just "*doesn't cut it*". That doesn't tell us anything on what specific feature you are missing.

Comment: What rud3y said is basically what I was looking for; the question has since stopped being relevant for me, but an answer would still be nice to know.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the variable name to get in the `User Variable` or `System variable` list in the `Environment Variable` of the system. When running in `WinPE`, there won't be an option like a prompt to get the user input even if `SET/P` is used. So you can manually change the value in the `User variable` to the option that you need to run, which will automatically included as the default option.